# How can I get path to current twig template dynamically?

Tags: templates, symfony, twig

Can I get current template name dynamically from any system variable?

For example, I has template `AcmeDemoBundle:Blog:post.html.twig`. I need to get this name from variable in template and if this template will be renamed to `AcmeDemoBundle:Blog:article.html.twig` - I also don't need to change it name in template manually. How can I do it?

P.S. It will be useful to debug for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twig files are converted into PHP classes, and `$this` is available as `_self` within a template.

Also, each generated PHP class has a getTemplateName method, such as:

```
public function getTemplateName()
{
    return "SomeBundle:Directory:my_file.html.twig";
}
```

So, to get your template name, you just need to call:

```
{{ _self.templateName }}
```

Comment: Did not know that. Nice!

Comment: Looks like in new Twig 2.x "_self" is actually a string, so no need to call extra method, just `{{ _self }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it in twig:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_template') }}
```

That will return the selected template name.
But if you open the debugger toolbar, you can find there all the available attributes.

Comment: I think you meant `attributes` instead of `attribute`?

Comment: And there are no `_template` key! Available keys are: `_controller`, `_locale`, `_route` and `route_params`

Comment: Thanks Victor, that was a typo. But where do you checking that? How do you render your template? Cause you have to have that value

Comment: I render this template with `renderView` method